# HMAC based Key exchange

Tags: authentication, key-exchange, hmac

Alice and Bob need to share public keys to sign/verify ephemeral keys. They have a secret key $K$.

1. Alice generates a 32 bytes random number $A$, computes $\operatorname{HMAC-SHA256}(K, M||A)$ and sends Bob the hash and plain $M$, $A$
2. Bob computes $\operatorname{HMAC-SHA256}(K, M||A)$ to check the hashes
3. If hashes match, Bob computes $N=\operatorname{HKDF}(A||K)$
4. Bob encrypts his public key $E_N(\mathit{PubKeyBob})$ using AES 256 GCM, and sends the cipher to Alice
5. Alice computes $N$ and decrypts the cipher, encrypts her public key $E_N(\mathit{PubKeyAlice})$, and sends Bob the cipher
6. Bob decrypts the cipher and they both have each other's public key

Is this a safe way to share public keys?

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - May I ask why the public keys need to be encrypted at all? Why can you assume the existence of a pre-shared secret, but not the existence of a pre-shared public key?

Comment: To prevent man in the middle attack. They have a pre-shared secret because they know each other.

Comment: If you have pre-shared $K$ why don't you just send the public keys encrypted with AES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have a pre-shared key $K$ and want to authenticate public keys, the simplest way would be for Alice to compute $T = HMAC(K, PubKeyAlice)$ and send $(PubKeyAlice,T)$ to Bob.
This authenticates the public key of Alice. There is no need to encrypt it, since it is a  public value anyway.

Comment: AES-GCM can be faster.

Comment: @kelalaka: Yes, depending on the platform GHASH could be faster. I could have written it in more general form T = MAC(K; PubKeyAlice) but since HMAC-SHA256 was explicitly mentioned in the question, I just used that instantiation.